# Passing parameters in using an array?

Tags: java, arrays, class, parameters

I'm using parameters for 27 different objects here; a snippet of the code is below:

```
//start of Region1
static ToEat region1EatOption2 = new ToEat("Maggie Mays","www.Maggiemays.co.uk","£££");
static ToEat region1EatOption3 = new ToEat("Villa Italia","www.VillaItalia.co.uk","££££");

static ToShop region1ShopOption2 = new ToShop("Deja vu","www.dejavubelfast.co.uk","£££");
static ToShop region1ShopOption3 = new ToShop("Rio Brazil","www.Riobrazil.co.uk","£££££");

static ToParty region1PartyOption1 = new ToParty("The M Club","www.Mclub.co.uk","£");
static ToParty region1PartyOption2 = new ToParty ("Queens Student Union","www.qubsu.co.uk","£££");
static ToParty region1PartyOption3 = new ToParty ("The Eglantine Inn","www.egbar.co.uk","£££££");
//end of Region 1

static Specials region1Specials1 = new Specials("The Eglantine Inn","6 shots = £6");
static Specials region1Specials2 = new Specials ("Deja vu" , "15% Student discount");
static Specials region1Specials3 = new Specials ("Viva Italia", "2 Course meal for £10");
```

This seems like a very long way of passing in the parameters. Is there a way that I can use an array for this info, and then use the array to pass in the parameters?

Comment: You could use arrays and a CSV file to store the values. Read in the values, splitting on commas, and pass them to the object arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
    // declare your ToEat-Entries here
    String[][] edibleEntries = new String[][] {
            {"Maggie Mays", "www.Maggiemays.co.uk", "£££"},
            {"Villa Italia","www.VillaItalia.co.uk","££££"},
            ...
        };

    // this creates an array containing the above entries
    ToEat[] edibles = new ToEat[edibleEntries.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < edibleEntries.length; i++) {
        edibles[i] = new ToEat(edibles[i][0], edibles[i][1], edibles[i][2]);
    }
```

The string array contains 3 strings for each entry, the loop creates ToEat-Objects from these entries and stores them into an array. You can do the same for the other object types and then pass the arrays.